# Imagick doesn't add metadata PHP

Tags: php, metadata, imagick

Hi everyone I read doc in php to use imagick and I want to add metadata to an image that is not contains one. So I decided to import image called `image.png`, add metadata and rewrite image called `new.png`

Here is code

```
$image = new Imagick("path/to/image/image.png");
$image->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'Imagick2');
$image->writeimage("path/to/image/app/new.png");
var_dump($image->getImageProperty('Exif:Make'));
```

I saw new image generated and var_dump() show : **string(8) "Imagick2"**

But using http://metapicz.com/ I got no metadata
[image: Metadata result]

Is there an issue with my code or website is not reliable ? How can be sure I have metadata inserted ?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Please hava a look at the comment on the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageproperty). It depends on the file type.

Comment: I already read this doc, I put similar code at the top but I'm not sure metadata is not imported because using  http://metapicz.com/  I don't see metadata imported

Comment: I mentioned the comment on the docs, not the docs itself.

Comment: Thank's @MarkusZeller here is, comment : "Please be aware that only 'comment' values are written to the file if it's a JPEG. This means that any other data, such as GPS data or Exif data can be 'modified' but will not be written to the file.  This might change in the future, but it hasn't change in 2 years." .

Comment: Oh, This is interesting, I create a repository for read metadata of PNG but the possibility of writing in them had not occurred to me. https://github.com/joserick/PNGMetadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing EXIF data to a PNG file.  PNG metadata support is poor in most software and until a few years ago (2016/17?) EXIF data wasn't part of the PNG specs.

ImageMagick (and ExifTool and Exiv2) had a non-standard way of embedding EXIF data in a PNG file but almost no software outside of those programs supported it.  Exiftool supports the new standard, but I'm not sure if the other two do or not.

I did a quick test on that website you linked to and it simply doesn't read most metadata in a PNG file.  My test file has over 1,400 embedded metadata tags and the only one the metapicz.com website picked up was the `IPTC:CopyrightNotice`.

You might try http://exif.regex.info to check for metadata.  It uses ExifTool on the backend and will give better results.

Comment: Thank you I found what I looking for with exif tool : ```exiftool -PoseHeadingDegrees="0" myfile.jpg ```